# How do I select the top k rows of a python polars dataframe for each group?

Tags: python, python-polars

The polars dataframe has a [top_k](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.top_k.html) method that can be used to select rows which contain the k largest values when sorting on a column. For example, the following code selects the two rows with the largest and second largest entry in the `val` column:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({'grp':['a','a','a','b','b','b'], 'val':[1,2,3,10,20,30], 'etc':[0,1,2,3,4,5]})

grp val etc
str i64 i64
"a" 1   0
"a" 2   1
"a" 3   2
"b" 10  3
"b" 20  4
"b" 30  5

df.top_k(2, by='val')

grp val etc
str i64 i64
"b" 30  5
"b" 20  4
```

My question is: how do I get the rows with top k values for each group? Specifically, I want the entire row and not just the value in the `val` column. I want to do something like this, but this doesn't work in polars because polars `GroupBy` doesn't have a `top_k` method:

```
df.groupby('grp').top_k(2, by='val') # doesnt work in polars

grp val etc
str i64 i64
"b" 30  5
"b" 20  4
"a" 3   2
"a" 2   1
```

I was able to come up with two ways: one using `apply` and another using sorting. Both of these are not desirable for performance reasons. `apply` is generally not recommended because [it's almost always significantly slower](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.dataframe.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html#polars.dataframe.groupby.GroupBy.apply). The sorting option is also not desirable as getting the top k elements uses a faster algorithm than sorting (for small k and large n, it's basically O(n) vs O(n log n)). So even though the following below work, I'm looking for other approaches. Is there any way to directly use a `top_k` method with polars groupby? That would be my ideal solution.

```
# works, but at expense of using apply method
df.groupby('grp').apply(lambda df: df.top_k(2, by='val'))

grp val etc
str i64 i64
"b" 30  5
"b" 20  4
"a" 3   2
"a" 2   1
```

```
# works, but at expense of sorting entire groups
df.groupby('grp').agg(pl.all().sort_by('val', descending=True).head(2)).explode('val','etc')

grp val etc
str i64 i64
"a" 3   2
"a" 2   1
"b" 30  5
"b" 20  4
```

- `df.groupby('grp').top_k(2, by='val')`, which doesn't work in polars
- `df.groupby('grp').apply(lambda df: df.top_k(2, by='val'))`, which works at the cost of using `apply`
- `df.groupby('grp').agg(pl.all().sort_by('val', descending=True).head(2)).explode('val','etc')`, which works at the cost of sorting

Comment: Could you `df.with_row_count().filter(pl.col('val').is_in(pl.col('val').top_k(2)).over('grp'))` and unique in the case of duplicates? Not sure how it fares on the cost scale.

Comment: Ah, I found https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7043 - it seems like perhaps `.GroupBy.top_k()` could also be implemented after that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll take a look. I was actually thinking of implementing a `.GroupBy.top_k()` myself, so this link to the issue is very helpful if I decide to go down that route.

Comment: It may also be worthwhile opening a feature request specifically about `.GroupBy.top_k` - it doesn't seem to have come up before.

Comment: You could do a `join` to add the `etc` column back in, although this might break if it's not 1:1 mapping I guess: `df.groupby('grp').agg(pl.col('val').top_k(2)).explode('val').join(df, on=['grp', 'val'])`

Comment: We need to add support for `top_k` of `struct` dtypes. I can take a look at that.

Comment: I thought the sort.head gets optimised behind the scenes into a top_k from this PR: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/7678 but I see the comment from @ritchie46 so I guess this does not apply to a groupby context

Comment: @ritchie46 anything you need from me? Should I open up a feature request? It's something I'd use very frequently at my job so I'm very eager to help however I can

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to group by a single variable then you can concat the results of `partition_by` using a list comprehension like this:

```
pl.concat([
    x.top_k(2, by='val')
        for x in df.partition_by('grp')
])
```

You should be able to make it faster by making the `x` lazy and using `collect_all`

```
pl.concat(pl.collect_all([
    x.lazy().top_k(2, by='val')
        for x in df.partition_by('grp')
]))
```

Alternatively you can use a regular groupby but it gets a bit verbose and is inefficient since it requires a full sort

```
(df
    .sort(['grp','val'], descending=[False, True])
    .groupby('grp')
    .agg(pl.exclude('grp').take(pl.arange(0,2)))
    .explode('val','etc')
    )
```

The `k` is the 2 in `arange`

Answer (score 0):

```
groups = ['grp', 'val']
top_n = 2

(
    df
    .sort(groups, descending=[False, True])
    .filter(pl.int_range(0, pl.len()).over(groups) < top_n)
)
```